# Background repeat to the right

Tags: html, css, image, background, repeat

How can I repeat my background image only on my site layout. My image is 1 pixel in width and 400 pixels in height and I wanted it to be 100% of the screen width.

I thought it was...

CSS:

```
#bg-image {
  background-image: url("images/bg.png")
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
  background-size: 100%; 
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bg-image"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

But this isn't working. I've had a look through other StackOverflow answers but I've unable to find one similar to my issue. Any helps appreciated cheers

Comment: change the background-repeat:repeat-x

Comment: `body { background: url(../images/bg.png); }`

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `height:auto` to the Div where your background image is applied and include it under a Div where you want it to extend.

```
<div class="OuterDiv">
    <div class="backgroundImage"></div>
</div>
```

`CSS`

```
.OuterDiv
{
    height:100%;
}

.backgroundImage
{
    background-image:url('someimage.png') repeat-x;
    height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you got confused `X` with `Y`. You should use:

```css
#bg-image {
    background-image: url("images/bg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#bg-image
{
background-image:url('paper.gif');
background-repeat:repeat-y;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
#bg-image {
    background-image: url("images/bg.png");
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yeah still nothing coming up

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for repeat horizontal image..

```
repeat-x : Work for Horizontal
repeat-y : Work for Vertical


'CSS
#bg-image {
background-image: url("images/bg.png")
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-size: 100%; 
}
HTML:
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="bg-image"> 
 </div>
</div>
```